# What is the address alignment of loaded DLL's in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, windows-10, loader

> What is the address alignment of loaded DLL's in Windows?

I have read somewhere that the page size of the system is 4096 bytes (0x1000), but I see all my DLL's loaded at an address multiple of 0x10000 bytes, e.g. 0x743f0000 for kernel32.dll.

Is the address alignment of loaded DLL's set to 0x10000 in Windows, or why do I experience this phenomena?

Please provide a source if possible, e.g. MSDN documentation.

Comment: What is this source that you speak of?

Comment: A read of [Windows Internals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx) and similar sources is likely to be your best bet. Note it may not be defined: ie. an update to Windows could change the alignment.

Comment: Section *Virtual Address Space Layouts* (in Chaper 10) of WIndows Internals (6th Ed) states the 64kb boundaries come from the (then) current ASLR implementation. Ie. will only apply to images participating in ASLR (which is most).

Comment: The only images participating in ASLR are DLL's right? I mean the PE documentation says: "The default behavior of the linker is to strip base relocations from executable (EXE) files."

Comment: @user111854: exes can (and should) participate in ASLR.  You have to opt in to it though :-(.

Comment: @MartinBonner - What do you mean by "You have to opt in to it though" :-) ?

Comment: @MartinBonner - Also, how could EXE's participate in ASLR, if Microsoft's own linker remove base relocations?

Comment: You have to pass the right options to the linker. (On my mobile now, so not easy to look up). Amongst other things I imagine that will stop the linker stripping relocation info.

Comment: @MartinBonner - I think what Microsoft do as default behavior is the "normal" way of doing things, e.g. EXE's should not participate in ASLR, since they always load at their prefered base address.

Comment: That's a very bad idea.  Really, it's terrible! Microsoft set EXEs to not participate in ASLR because it breaks too many badly coded programs.

Comment: If you are sure, I believe you :-) (you seem to have somewhat experience!). Thanks for the discussion.